# what kind of Vibration Motor should I choose and how can I achieve my goal?

Tags: motors, vibration, experimental-physics

I'm building a vibration table for testing the durability of a metal rack, I want the vibration motor to create an even and average vertical displacement to the table, what kind of Vibration Motor should I choose and how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: please read the comment from @chrisl at your first question and follow the advice ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/94601/vibration-motor?noredirect=1